# How can I create a fixed size Gtk.TextView in Gtk+3?

Tags: gtk, textview, gtk3

I have a Gtk.TextView inside a Gtk.Fixed and I set it its width and height and wrap mode.

My problem is that I need to avoid the TextView expanding when the user inserts more text than what fits in the set size. In that case I just need to prevent the user from keeping writing.

Any help?

Answer (score -3):

If you have a single line entry as input better use textentry instead of textview.
For text entry your can set the maximum length of textentry.

For development of UI using glade.
Moreover if your UI changes depending on configuration file from server,
there is a solution for this also, have all the widgets in the window, show/hide the widgets depending on the config file from server.

Comment: thanks for your answer! it was a multiline input unluckily :( The UI changes so much that using glade would only save a few lines of code, that's the thing.

Answer (score -4):

why dont you use GLADE for UI development ?. 
It provides more handy ways to achieve your task.

In glade you have all the options to set, you can cross verify and check in real time.

Comment: I had some limitations that won't allow me to use glade (the UI configuration was downloaded from a server at start up time).